# Jupyter notebook switched to JSON; kernel missing from menu bar

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

To start, I'm a complete beginner to python. I have no prior experience in coding.

I was in Jupyter Notebook last night, and it was working fine. Then, I opened it this morning, and it's suddenly in JSON mode. I tried to google how to fix this, and it said to restart the kernel. The problem is, the kernel dropdown from my menu bar is now missing.

[image of menu bar in jupyter noteboook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzcgy.png)

I have zero idea what's happened or how to fix any of it.

I tried closing out of everything and restarting the notebook via the windows command prompt.

Comment: did you close the tab and reopen it ?

Comment: I did--a few times. I managed to fix it by completely sheer, stupid luck. I renamed the file by adding .ipynb. Reloaded. Suddenly it's working. I have no idea why that fixed it or why it switched to JSON in the first place. God bless anyone who works with python for a living because y'all have the patience of a saint.